# How to scroll page apart from window.scrollTo()

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox, spotify

I've got a test assignment, which asks me to parse Spotify playlists for some info (artist, album, song name, and duration). **I'm not allowed to use Spotify API**. So far I've managed to retrieve the info required, but I've only first 100 records. JavaScript's `window.scrollTo()` for some reason doesn't work on [open.spotify.com](https://open.spotify.com) (just try it in your browser), and I can't find any other way to fully load the page. [Here](https://open.spotify.com/playlist/4zvcnVdqu3mKbvI5jDrWzU) is Spotify playlist I'm working with, it contains 931 songs

Comment: The window is not scrolling, but a div inside the window.
Maybe this will help:
document.getElementsByClassName('os-viewport')[1].scrollTo(0,1000)

Comment: This question doesn't provide a MVCE - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. For example, how are you retrieving this info and what does it have to do with window.scrollTo(), you tagged the question with selenium but didn't post minimal code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ryano for providing an actual answer. Spotify pages can be scrolled down by firing

```
document.getElementsByClassName('os-viewport')[1].scrollTo(0, document.getElementsByClassName('os-viewport')[1].scrollHeight)
```